# What statistical test to use for repeated measures, categorical data?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures

doing a research project and have been trying to use combination of google/chatgpt but am still not sure. the first research question is testing whether or not kids have increased in empathy following an intervention. it would be

- one group (i.e. all participants), repeated measures, categorical data (before the intervention they choose between options A and B, then intervention happens, then they choose again, if statistically significant increase in people choosing option A, then null hypothesis is rejected).

there are technically three groups in the experiment, as the second research question is looking at differences between each group in intervention efficacy, and I know that would require mixed design ANOVA - but since for this research question I'm just seeing if, on the whole, there is a difference, I don't think it's relevant that there are three different groups.

I've found a range of answers - McNemar's, Sign Test etc. But am not sure which is most relevant?
Thank you so much!!!!!